# Non Local Means Filter Optimization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

I'm trying to write a Non-Local Means filter for an assignment. I've written the code in two ways, but the method I'd expect to be quicker is much slower than the other method.

Method 1: (This method is slower)

```
for i = 1:size(I,1)
    tic
    sprintf('%d/%d',i,size(I,1))
    for j = 1:size(I,2)
        w = exp((-abs(I-I(i,j))^2)/(h^2));

        Z = sum(sum(w));
        w = w/Z;

        sumV = w .* I;

        NL(i,j) = sum(sum(sumV));
    end
    toc
end
```

Method 2: (This method is faster)

```
for i = 1:size(I,1)
    tic
    sprintf('%d/%d',i,size(I,1))
    for j = 1:size(I,2)
        Z = 0;
        for k = 1:size(I,1)
            for l = 1:size(I,2)
                w = exp((-abs(I(i,j)-I(k,l))^2)/(h^2));

                Z = Z + w;
            end
        end

        sumV = 0;
        for k = 1:size(I,1)
            for l = 1:size(I,2)
                w = exp((-abs(I(i,j)-I(k,l))^2)/(h^2));
                w = w/Z;

                sumV = sumV + w * I(k,l);
            end
        end

        NL(i,j) = sumV;
    end
    toc
end
```

I really thought that MATLAB would be optimized for Matrix operations. Is there reason it isn't in this code? The difference is pretty large. For a `512x512` image, with `h = 0.05`, one iteration of the outer loop takes `24-28` seconds for Method 1 and `10-12` seconds for Method 2.

Comment: What is `h` in the second method?

Comment: `h` is the Non-Local Means Filtering Parameter. For both methods, `h=0.05`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods are not doing the same thing. In Method 2, the term `abs(I(i,j)-I(k,l))` in the `w=` expression is being squared, which is fine because the term is just a single numeric value.

However, in Method 1, the term `abs(I-I(i,j))` is actually a matrix (The numeric value `I(i,j)` is being subtracted from every element in the matrix `I`, returning a matrix again). So, when this term is squared with the `^` operator, matrix multiplication is happening. My guess, based on Method 2, is that this is not what you intended. If instead, you want to square each element in that matrix, then use the `.^` operator, as in `abs(I-I(i,j)).^2`

Matrix multiplication is a much more computation intensive operation, which is likely why Method 1 takes so much longer.

Comment: Oooh! Thanks! I did intend to perform term-wise multiplication. `.^` reduces the running time to `2-3` seconds!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have not preassigned `NL`, that both methods are in the same function (or are scripts and you didn't clear `NL` between function runs). This would have slowed the first method by quite a bit.

Try the following: Create a function for both methods. Run each method once. Then use the `profiler` to see where each function spends most of its time.

Comment: They're separate functions, not scripts. I've initialized NL to `zeros` in both cases. I'll try `profiler` and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

A much faster implementation (Vectorized) could be achieved using `im2col`:

1. Create a Vector out of each neighborhood.
2. Using predefined indices calculate the distance between each patch.
3. Sum over the values and the weights using `sum` function.

This method will work with no loop at all.